# change org-insert-heading shortcut

Tags: emacs, shortcut, org-mode

I would like to change the shortcut defined for org-insert-heading (in org-mode, in emacs).

It is `M-<RET>` and I would like to have `C-c C-j` (like in AUCTex mode).

How do I do this (there is no variable in org-customize) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to erikstokes' answer, you can use `define-key` with the appropriate keymap.  Set this in your `.emacs.d/init.el` :

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'org-insert-heading)
```

This will add it to the org-mode keymap, and it will not add the key locally every time the mode is set to `org-mode` (it shouldn't matter, but running it on every hook can cause issues for some commands.

Comment: I get `Error in private config: config.el, (void-variable org-mode-map)` :/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to bind `C-c C-j` to the function you want.  Assuming that you only want it bound this way in org-mode, add

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (local-set-key "\C-c\C-j" 'org-insert-heading)
         ))
```

to your `.emacs` file and restart Emacs (or just reload your `.emacs`).  Now every time you load a file in org-mode the `local-set-key` function will be run and set the keys the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at "org-auctex-keys.el", a minor mode which I created to offer AUCTeX key bindings within Org documents.

Check it out at https://github.com/fniessen/org-auctex-key-bindings.

Comment: Very useful comment for people like me who are used to AUCTex shortcuts. I use now this minor mode. Thanks.

Comment: I've added extra key bindings. Pull the latest version, and have a look. If you see some other important key bindings, let me know (via GitHub issues or on the Org-mode ML).

Answer (score 0):

(org-defkey org-mode-map "\C-c\C-j" 'org-meta-return)

Comment: I have a `Symbol's function definition is void: org-defkey` when I paste your code